# Splitting daterange into columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-range

I have defined a table in PostgreSQL with a column of type daterange, and now need to split it into two columns of type date (start and end date). How can I do that, I was unable to find anything.

For example, I have [2012-01-01,2015-10-10) in column period and need: start_date 2012-01-01 and end_date 2015-10-10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lower` and `upper`

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-range.html

```
create table t (period daterange);
insert into t (period) values ('[2012-01-01,2015-10-10)');
```

---

```
select  (period).lower
       ,(period).upper

from    t
;
```